# What should be the maximum provisioned concurrency for lambda function triggered from API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

What should be the ideal provisioned concurrency set on AWS Lambda function which is serving HTTP requests using API gateway to reduce latency for API requests

Comment: How many HTTP requests do you have per second?

Comment: Assuming 100 requests/second does it co-relates directly to number of requests at the same instant which we get from cloud watch metrics?

Comment: Depends on how long your lambda runs for. If a single request runs for more then 1 second on lambda, then you need 100 concurrent lambda executions to handle that.

Comment: Ok , but the amount of time it takes to provision them is high

Comment: Only the first time is high. lambda keeps your functions ready for use for some time after first invocation anyway. Don't need provisioned concurrency for that.

Comment: yeah but lets say after the new version is deployed 
how long it takes to propagate that change across provisioned lambdas is it less?
also all provisioned lambdas start serving requests once they are running same artifact?

Comment: No. You will have a period of some functions running old and new content. There was some reference for that, let me try to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Answering based on the comments.

Once you updated your function, existing instances of the function will still run the old version for few minutes. From [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270926&tstart=0):

> While we do not abort in-flight invocations, we will aggressively eliminate copies of the old code; this typically happens within a minute of a function being updated. That means that for up to about 5-6 minutes (the max duration of a function, plus a little bit) **you can experience either/both versions in use**; after that, you should see only the newly deployed) version executing.

The post refers to 5-6 minutes, but now function execution time is 15 minutes. Thus its not clear if this time extended as well.

To somehow control this process, you can look at [canary lambda deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-canary-deployments-of-aws-lambda-functions-with-alias-traffic-shifting/). You can also perform [canary deployments for API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html).

Comment: @SwanandKeskar No problem. Glad I could help.